# Can't find sequence of bytes in IDA while debugging

Tags: ida, address

While debugging a program, I have an address `0011E028` in `eax` that points to another address: `680df44`:
[image]

I wanted to see what appear inside the address `680df44` so I go to `Search > sequence of bytes...` (Alt+B) in IDA and searched for `680df44` but it didn't find this address:

```
Searching down CASE-INSENSITIVELY for binary pattern:
    44 DF 80 06
Search failed.
Command "AskBinaryText" failed
```

I thought maybe the order was incorrect so I change it to `40f40d68` and it still failed:

```
Searching down CASE-INSENSITIVELY for binary pattern:
    68 0D F4 40
Search failed.
Command "AskBinaryText" failed
```

Comment: that looks like chall 3 from Flare ;)

Comment: Hmnm maybe :) I am asking technical questions, not asking for clues or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can convert the address to one line.
This is before:
[image]

If I put the cursor on `68h` and press in the keyboard `d` it add it to one line and complete it like that:
[image]

Another thing, the address was incorrect, it was `0044DF68` and **not** `680df44`.
So I can just jump to this address by pressing the `g` key and type the address `0044DF68`.